# Getting started with nrf51882a

Tags: c++, c, keil, nrf51

I'm currently trying to start with the nordic development kits, I installed all the tools required to be able to start the development & also I get some files which have the following:

1. drivers' codes ?& header files which contain their functions.
2. some examples using some of these drivers

the main problem I faced now is I can't understand the drivers code or I can't use their functions, I don't know from where I can get an illustration or a step by step examples using the drivers, I know that's much difficult to find that, but I'd like to know how to use these drivers or external drivers available or how to deal with these codes

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The Nordic team have done a very nice job in creating everything needed to get developers started. In general, there are three places to find all the information that you would need:-

[The nRF51x SDK](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF51-SDK): 
This is the software development kit which includes drivers, libraries, and most importantly numerous examples on using the drivers. The examples clearly demonstrate how the different components can be used.

[The nRF51 Infocenter](http://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/topic/com.nordic.infocenter.nrf51/dita/nrf51/nrf51_series.html?cp=2):
The infocentre is Nordic's web library for their chipsets and their specifications. Specifically have a look at Softdevice API and Message Sequence Charts.

[The Nordic Devzone:](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/questions/)
This is equivalent to StackOverflow but is specifically for Nordic related questions and also includes blogs, tutorials, and examples.

I hope this helps.